Как через локальную сеть открыть проект на телефоне?
Пишу на Avalonia в браузере все запускается, а открыть сайт через локальную сеть на телефоне нет,подскажите как это можно сделать

Авалония - сайт? (погуглил, речь про WASM походу) А так, пробрасывайте порты, настраивайте фаервол.
